# How can I invoke methods from another form? C#

Tags: c#, forms, invoke

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a method on another form in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837788/calling-a-method-on-another-form-in-c-sharp)

I have 2 forms in my program. Is there a way that, when clicking a button from `form1`, I can invoke a method in the `form2` class?

This is what I have tried. clear_grid() is the method I have in form 2 (named GameForm) and this is the event listener for the button in form 1.

```
private void yesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    this.Hide();
    GameForm.ActiveForm.Invoke(clear_grid());
}
```

Of course this is not working. Is there a similar way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a method on another form in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/837788/calling-a-method-on-another-form-in-c-sharp) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890754/call-a-method-from-another-form or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442891/calling-a-method-in-another-form-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

If `GameForm` is an instance of your second form class and `clear_grid` is a public method, then whats wrong with simply calling a method?

```
private void yesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    this.Hide();
    GameForm.clear_grid();
}
```

Comment: Ok I managed to do this:

GameForm gf = (ConnectFour.GameForm) GameForm.ActiveForm;
gf.clear_grid(); 

I didn't know I can cast this so I thought I couldnt invoke the method that way! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
(Form1)this.Parent.RefreshTable();
```